# How to not forget the washed clothes in the washing machine

Tags: home, technology

At times I forget the washed clothes in the washing machine which makes the clothes stink and more crushed. The beep from the machine indicating the end of wash is not sufficient to alert since it is not so loud enough to be heard.

Does anybody else also face this problem ? Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

I set a kitchen timer to go off about 20 minutes after the wash cycle will complete. That way, if I step out or I'm in the middle of doing something else, I get that second reminder that the load is done.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Roberts answer, most people walk around with their phone these days - Simply set a timer on your phone. Even if it isn't on you, it can usually be heard around the house assuming the volume is set to high.

Answer (score 1):

If you like home automation (as I do), you could add a [magnetic door contact sensor](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51anbYLBR0L._SY355_.jpg) to your washing mashine door, let opening the tray set an alarm and opening the lid disable the alarm.

That alarm should be delayed and repeat of course. You can also use IFTTT's Maker channel to easily send you push notifications.

You actually gave me an idea on what to do next. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put an alarm in your phone when you put in the laundry for approximately 1 hour. Snooze it or next time set it later if the machine isn't finished yet.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The phone alarm has been suggested before. But often I start the machine and then go out. So when the alarm beeps, I'm not at home to open it and I forget it later. So I put the alarm to the time at which I know I'll return.

In my experience clothes can be wet inside the machine for up to 12 hours before they start to smell. Also, insted of a normal softener, use a hygienic softener, which destroys 99,9% of bacteria. Bacteria are the source of the smell.